# Como agregar una clase en html cuando entra a un if sin utilizar tanto código html dentro del Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, if

Tengo una funcion que convierte los characteres en en password si un checkbox esta activado. Mi pregunta es si hay una mejor forma de hacer lo que estoy haciendo en mi codigo. Sin tener que duplicar el mismo html que solo tiene una diferencia.

```
$(".add-row").click(function() {
    var param = $("#param").val();
    var valor = $("#valor").val();

    if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked === true) {
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td class='hidetext'>" + valor + "</td></tr>";
    } else {
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td>" + valor + "</td></tr>";
    }
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Lo que hace es que si el checkbox es true que el markup muestre el class como hidden text nada mas. La class hidden text solo hace que se comviertan a discs

```
.hidetext {
-webkit-text-security: disc;}
```

Como puedo hacer mas eficiente el if del var markup?

Este es mi HTML

```
<table style="width: 50%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Parametro</th>
                    <th>Valor
                    <th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `removeClass` de jQuery dentro de tu chequeo de `if`. Si la condición `checked` no se cumple le quita la clase.

```
$(".add-row").click(function() {
    var param = $("#param").val();
    var valor = $("#valor").val();
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td class='hidetext'>" + valor + "</td></tr>";

    $("table tbody").append(markup);

    if (!document.getElementById("myCheck").checked) {
      $('.hidetext').removeClass('hidetext');
    }

    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```